# How do I have a fixed aside?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

How do I do an aside like this?
Like the one on the left of the web
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

i tried this, and it works:
[image]

but when i go down to the main page it has a problem:
[image]

this is my code:

```js
<div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="flex">
        <aside className="overflow-y-auto sticky h-[89vh] w-[25%] ">
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
          <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2> <h2>holaa</h2>{' '}
        </aside>
        <main className="ml-40 grid grid-cols-3 gap-10">
          {products
            ? products.map((product) => (
                <ProductCard product={product} key={product.id} />
              ))
            : null}
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `sticky`, use `fixed`:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/CBTrk0poR3

Answer (score 0):

take a good look at this code. it will help you to get what you want.

HTML

```
<header>header</header>
<nav>nav</nav>
<section>section</section>
<aside>aside</aside>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: segoe-ui_normal, Segoe UI, Segoe, Segoe WP, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "nav section aside"
        "footer footer footer";
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 50px;
    grid-template-columns: 15% 1fr 18%;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 10px;
}
header {
    background: #707070;
    grid-area: header;
}

nav {
    background: #C9BFBF;
    grid-area: nav;
}

section {
    background: #ABABAB;
    grid-area: section;
}

aside {
    background: #C9C9C9;
    grid-area: aside;
}

footer {
    background: #707070;
    grid-area: footer;
}

header,
nav,
section,
aside,
footer {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

ref : https://codepen.io/MSEdgeDev/pen/mMQqZX